# Apply preprocessing to the dataset

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, image-preprocessing

I am implementing a paper on image segmentation in pytorch. I am required to do some preprocessing steps but as I am trying it the first time so I am unable to incorporate them in the traditional pipeline.
Following are the preprocessing steps-

1)   N(w, h) = I(w, h) − G(w, h), (1)
where N is the normalized image, I is the original image, and G is the Gaussian blurred image with kernel size 65*65 and 0 mean and standard deviation 10.

2)Normalizing the mean image and dividing each pixel by average standard deviation.

Following is my code snippet for the above steps-

```
def gaussian_blur(img):
    image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(65,65),10)
    new_image = img - image
return image

def normalise(img):
    img_normalised = np.empty(img.shape)
    img_std = np.std(img)
    img_mean = np.mean(img)
    img_normalized = (img-img_mean)/imgs_std

    for i in range(img.shape[1]):
        img_normalized[i] = (img_normalized - 
         np.mean(img_normalized))/np.std(img_normalized)
return img_normalized
```

I am really not sure how to add above functions in the traditional pytorch data-loaders pipeline like first I should load the dataset using `ImageFolder` and then apply or first apply and then use `ImageFolder` method.

Comment: I'm too lazy to provide a working code right now, but you can read about [Generic Transforms](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#generic-transforms) to do it in the easy way.

Comment: As @Berriel said, the Generic Transforms work fine, but, I'd also recommend you the [imgaug](https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You may find some useful codes there.

Comment: @Berriel any ideas on how to write a lambda function for multiple expression as my gaussian blur function has 2 expressions, I thought for long but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @Mark if you look at the code of [`transforms.Lambda(...)`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/8d580a1f087d1758cf181269d13ed717dba0c2bd/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py#L301-L316), you'll notice that you can pass any callable. Wrap your transformation in a function and just pass it. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it-

The solution of the first part is first defining the required function and then calling in the transforms using the generic transforms in the following way-

```
def gaussian_blur(img):
   image = np.array(img)
   image_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(65,65),10)
   new_image = image - image_blur
   im = Image.fromarray(new_image)
return im
```

Solution of second part is to go through every image and calculate the mean and std deviation and then finally calling the mean and std deviation values in the transforms.-

```
   train_mean = []
   train_std = []

   for i,image in enumerate(train_loader,0):
       numpy_image = image[0].numpy()
       batch_mean = np.mean(numpy_image, axis=(0, 2, 3))
       batch_std = np.std(numpy_image, axis=(0, 2, 3))

       train_mean.append(batch_mean)
       train_std.append(batch_std)

   train_mean = torch.tensor(np.mean(train_mean, axis=0))
   train_std = torch.tensor(np.mean(train_std, axis=0))

    print('Mean:', train_mean)
    print('Std Dev:', train_std)
```

Final transform calling looks like this-

```
data_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomCrop(512,512),
                                 transforms.Lambda(gaussian_blur),
                                 transforms.RandomRotation([+90,+180]),
                                 transforms.RandomRotation([+180,+270]),
                                 transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                 transforms.ToTensor(),
                                 transforms.Normalize(mean=train_mean, std=train_std)
                               ])
```